# Chrome Extension CSS not being injected

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Ive been at this for a few weeks now. The javascript works fine and after all this time i assumed it was a lie that you can use css with chrome extensions. Ive been making entire guis with javascript.

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "",
  
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["https://www.google.com/"],
        "js": ["script.js"],
        "css": ["main.css"]
      }
    ]
  }
```

The javascript gets loaded perfectly fine in the sources but i dont see the css file or any changes happening. Here is this css:

```
body {
    background: red !important;
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Your `matches` applies only to the main page and not to the results page. Add `*` at the end of it then reload both the extension and the tab.

Comment: Your extension made the background red. Are you saying that DevTools can't see CSS injections?

Comment: wOxxOm you were right also it still doesnt show up in sources, I expected it too and that made me assume it wasnt being injected. The matches wasnt always the issue because i know for a fact it was correct at some point but because i didnt see it in sources i assumed it didnt work.